# How to write grok for this log file

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to figure out a grok pattern for the logfile below. It contains 1 line of Success log and 1 entry of Warning log.

```
2016-09-03T12:53:31-04:00   DEV SampleFileService   INFO    512132:414618:SampleFileService-2-FTS   EXECUTING: Error Handling Client Request started

2016-09-03T12:53:31-04:00   DEV SampleFileService   WARNING 512133:414618:SampleFileService-2-FTS   ERROR: Error while sending ErrorHandler request to IEHS Queue: test.queue.publish
Retry count 1 of 3, 
Error: 
<ns0:ErrorReport xmlns:ns0="http://www.tibco.com/pe/EngineTypes">
    <StackTrace>Job-414618 Error in [Process-Path!!]
There was an unexpected error while sending a message.
    at com.tibco.plugin.share.jms.impl.JMSSender.send(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.plugin.share.jms.impl.JMSSender.send(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.plugin.jms.JMSAbstractTransmitActivity.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.plugin.Activity.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.TaskImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.Job.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.Job.k(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.JobDispatcher$JobCourier.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.JobDispatcher$JobCourier.run(Unknown Source)
caused by: com.tibco.plugin.share.jms.impl.JMSExceptionWrapper: javax.jms.JMSException: Failure storing message
    at com.tibco.plugin.share.jms.impl.JMSPluginException.&lt;init&gt;(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.plugin.share.jms.impl.JMSSender.send(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.plugin.share.jms.impl.JMSSender.send(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.plugin.jms.JMSAbstractTransmitActivity.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.plugin.Activity.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.TaskImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.Job.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.Job.k(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.JobDispatcher$JobCourier.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.pe.core.JobDispatcher$JobCourier.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failure storing message
    at com.tibco.tibjms.Tibjmsx.buildException(Tibjmsx.java:612)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._publish(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:1544)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsMessageProducer._publish(TibjmsMessageProducer.java:246)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueSender.send(TibjmsQueueSender.java:74)
    ... 9 more
</StackTrace>
    <Msg>There was an unexpected error while sending a message.</Msg>
    <FullClass>com.tibco.plugin.share.jms.impl.JMSPluginException</FullClass>
    <Class>JMSPluginException</Class>
    <ProcessStack>Stack-Path!!</ProcessStack>
    <MsgCode>BW-JMS-100039</MsgCode>
</ns0:ErrorReport>
```

Comment: Could you indicate what you want to extract from your log? Because if there is no information to retrieve, the grok filter is useless.

Comment: Also to help you: [grok filter tester](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result), [grok filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) and [grok patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).

Comment: Considering the first line, it should be
timestamp -> 2016-09-03T12:53:31-04:00 ,
Env -> Dev , Application -> SampleFileService , 
Level -> Info ,
Thread -> 512132:414618:SampleFileService-2-FTS ,
Status -> EXECUTING,
Message -> (Reminder of the message)
2nd line has more information to be logged for the field 'Message'..

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use the multiline [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-multiline.html)/[codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) on your input so all of your message is grouped together. The configuration is the same in both case :

```
multiline {
  pattern => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
  negate => "true" 
  what => "previous"
}
```

This will group the lines not beginning with an ISO 8601 date with the previous one. So in the case of your second message, all the line will be together.

Then you can then use this grok pattern:

```
grok {
  match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{WORD:env}%{SPACE}%{WORD:application}%{SPACE}%{WORD:level}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:thread}%{SPACE}%{WORD:status}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
}
```

Comment: I did try few combinations, as a newbie, the pattern syntax is little confusing.. the logs I was trying to analyze had some tab delimits (it turned out to be a 'space' after pasting here... never mind :) ). Also I couldn't combine string like '512132:414618:SampleFileService-2-FTS ' into a single word. It was getting split as well. Though I referred to https://github.com/hpcugent/logstash-patterns/blob/master/files/grok-patterns I din't know where to be applying in the above log message..However appreciate your help, in no angle u are fool... would say savior. Thanks much..

Comment: You're welcome. Did it work? If it does not/does not give an expected result, don't hesitate adding information to your question